# How to make SASS ignore math operation?

Tags: css, sass

I have this SASS line:

```
{ grid-area: 3 / 10 / 4 / 11; }
```

I'm trying to make the grid area change based on the number of grid columns:

```
{ grid-area: 3 / 10 / 4 / $grid-columns + 1; }
```

But when I do this, SASS interprets the `/` characters as a division, generating this as a result:

```
{ grid-area: 0.64932 }
```

Is there anyway to make SASS ignore the `/` characters and only do the `$grid-columns + 1` operation, so this would be the final code:

```
$grid-columns = 10
{ grid-area: 3 / 10 / 4 / $grid-columns + 1; }
{ grid-area: 3 / 10 / 4 / 11; }
```

Comment: There seems to be info on how to get round this (it's described as an 'interim' situation but I can't find the date or anything like version numbers) at: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div

Comment: thank you A. Haworth, using `list.slash` fixed my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it as a number

```
{ grid-area: 3 / 10 / 4 / #{$grid-columns + 1}; }
```